# What Beep() method to use with Terminal Services Server?

Tags: c#, citrix, terminal-services

```
 System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
```

That's what I use at the moment but it does not Beep on client(Windows7) within a Terminalserver/ Citrix(Windows2008).

What should I use instead?

Comment: Try to turn on the speakers and turn up the volume.  Check if *any* audio is capable of being heard.  Console.Beep() is an alternative.  The obvious google query is "terminal server audio playback", first hit is [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307071).  Show your research so we don't have to point out the obvious.

Comment: If you're connected via a termnial to Citrix, and you invoke Beep() on the Windows2008 box, the client won't hear it. Unless you sit (physically) next to the server.

Comment: Off-topic: that's a funny title... :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try playing a WAV file instead. You can use one of the built-in Windows system sounds and play that. Just ensure that your Citrix environment is configured to remote audio to the client.

Comment: You do realise that's exactlyy what they're doing?

Comment: Going off Shai's comment I thought it might have been mapping to one of the old beep APIs that plays a tone on the motherboard (which is generally used for reporting errors at bootup).